# PHPUnit data provider dynamically creation

Tags: php, phpunit, automated-tests

I have very interesting question about PHPUnit data providers.

```
protected $controller;

protected function setUp()
{
    $this->controller = new ProductController(); 
}

 /**
 * @covers       ProductsController::createItem
 * @dataProvider getTestDataProvider
 * @param number $name
 */
public function testCreateItem($name)
{   
    $prod = $this->controller->createItem($name);
    $id = $prod->getId;
    $this->assertInternalType('int', $id);
    $this->assertInstanceOf('Product', $prod);
}

/**
 * @covers           ProductsController::getItemInfo
 * @depends          testCreateItem
 * @param number $id
 */
public function testGetItemInfo($id)
{
    $info = $this->controller->getItemInfo($id);
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('id',$info);
    $this->assertEquals($id, $info['id']);
}
```

I use `getTestDataProvider` to get test data from CSV file. Then `testCreateItem` create 10 new products from CSV rows.

How can I create an array of `$id` of new products and use it as Data provider for `testGetItemInfo`? I can't store it in SESSION or file because provider functions run's before SetUp.

Maybe someone has already faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have only idea with static field (maybe not the best, but if someone has better I'll look).

```
private static $ids;

/**
 * @dataProvider some
 */
public function testT1($id)
{
    self::$ids[] = $id;
}

/**
 * @depends testT1
 */
public function testT2()
{
    var_dump(self::$ids);
}

public function some()
{
    return [
        [1],
        [2],
        [3]
    ];
}
```

You must remember that field is visible in all class so if you want use another data set you must nullify this field.